# Apparmor Failure in Ubuntu Desktop 21.10

Tags: apparmor, 21.10

Are there anyone experiencing failure with Apparmor which prevents boot? Besides several of the Apparmor profiles seem corrupted.

Comment: The answer is probably yes. _Someone_ is having issues with it too. But if you [edit] your question to include the exact issue you are having, we can try to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I'm having issues after upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10.
System does not boot and hangs on apparmor loading. I was able to boot in using the old kernel 5.11.0-37-generic but it fails with 5.13.0-19.19

Answer (score 0):

After few days there was a kernel update to 5.13.0-20-generic and now I'm able to login without apparmor failure on Ubuntu 21.10.