# Stuck on cryptsetup while upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: upgrade, 21.04, cryptsetup, 21.10

I had enabled Full Disk Encryption on my Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop, now while upgrading to 21.10 and now the system is stuck on cryptsetup once i entered the correct password. What do i do next as it has been over 2hours and the system is still stuck on cryptsetup.

Comment: You did a backup of all important data before trying a version upgrade of course.

Comment: That looks like the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369512/apparmor-failure-in-ubuntu-desktop-21-10